# Convolution equation

Tags: convolution, deconvolution

Given functions $g$ and $u$, what can we say about solutions of the equation:
$$
f \star g = u
$$
where $\star$ is the convolution and $f$ is the unknown function. When does it exist? Do we know an explicit solution? All solutions?

I am not specifying smoothness or domain here as I am also interested in answer in specific cases on $g$ and $u$.

Comment: $\hat f=\frac {\hat u} {\hat g}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-state the problem.  I am assuming the question is:

Given

$\int_{R^d} f(\tau)g(t - \tau)d\tau = u(t)$,

assuming $g(t)$ and $u(t)$ are known, how can we determine $f(t)$?  This is an integral equation of the first kind, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation

The response in the comments above reflects the solution given in the above link.  What I don't know is under what conditions the inverse Fourier transform will work.  Probably only when the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ both exist.